# How can I stop my map algebra being limited to the size of my smallest raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, raster-calculator, map-algebra

I have five input rasters and I'm using map algebra to find areas where all of them have a value over 75, areas where all of them are over 25, and areas where one or more are under 25. I can do this with:

```
Con((Raster("RISK-CH.tif") > 74.9) & (Raster("RISK-MI.tif") > 74.9) & (Raster("RISK-RE.tif") > 74.9) & (Raster("RISK-SE.tif") > 74.9) & (Raster("RISK-SO.tif") > 74.9), 100, Con((Raster("RISK-CH.tif") > 24.9) & (Raster("RISK-MI.tif") > 24.9) & (Raster("RISK-RE.tif") > 24.9) & (Raster("RISK-SE.tif") > 24.9) & (Raster("RISK-SO.tif") > 24.9), 50, 0))
```

The problem is that all of my rasters are slightly different shapes and sizes, and some have small holes, but I dont want to completely discount areas with no data. The output is the size and shape of the smallest input. I won't allow them to make the highest category, but if all the available datasets are above 25 I want the cell to still make my middle category.

I've tried using

> ((Raster("RISK-CH.tif") > 74.9) |
>   IsNull(Raster("RISK-CH")))

but that gives me the exact same output, I've tried

```
((Raster("RISK-CH.tif") > 74.9) | (Raster("RISK-CH.tif") IS nodata))
```

and

```
((Raster("RISK-CH.tif") > 74.9) | (Raster("RISK-CH.tif") = NODATA))
```

but both of these throw errors.

Is the issue to do with my boolean logic, or can a raster calculator output not be larger than the smallest inputs?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the [environment settings](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_geoprocessing_environments/001w00000035000000/) for your processing tool.

For a "one shot", click oon the environment > processing extent > union of inputs (or specify your own extent)

If you want this choice to be remembered, go to the menu > geoprocessing > Environment settings.

In Python, you can set the environment using arcpy.env

Comment: Thanks @radouxju but that doesn't seem to change the result. I don't think its an extent issue because the holes in the small raster also appear in the output.

Comment: You mentioned that the output had the size of the smallest raster, so this at least should solve part of your problem. For the second problem, I usually try to avoid very long "con" string because its difficult to pick up errors. In your case, the workaround could be to reclassify  zero/ones rasters using "IsNull()" ," > 75"  and " < 25 "  , then you sum the three sets of rasters and you can extract your classes in an easier way

Answer (score 1):

Mosaic to new raster using union of inputs. Set extent to this raster. Reclass all 5 into 0, 1, 2, 4, with zero replacing nodata. Use combine rasters to get unique combinations